# What is the most Pythonic way of handling standard input?

Tags: python

I've started doing programming contests/challenges, and often the questions involve reading in from standard input. I've been doing

```
import fileinput

inputLines = []

for line in fileinput.input():
    inputLines.append(line)
```

I then can do whatever calculations I need to do with `inputLines`. Is there a more Pythonic (i.e., better) way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read from `stdin`, not from any files named in the command line, then you should not use `fileinput`.

If you want a list containing the lines from `stdin`, then:

```
import sys
inputLines = list(sys.stdin)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print "The line was", line
```

Comment: What advantages does iterating over sys.stdin have compared to iterating over fileinput()?

Comment: @djlovesupr3me as the name says, it is used for reading file. If you doesn't specify any file name, it reads stdin.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) is the flexible way to do it in Python, given they made a module just to do that.

If you know more about what type of input you will be reading, there might be libraries that are better suited to your needs. For example, I do a lot of numerical work, so `pandas` works great for me because it has a `read_csv`. Take a look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html) (and try and tell us more about specific reading needs, if you can narrow it down).